# Accumulator function for tag cloud

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a tail-recursion function that will look at a list of distinct words, a list of all words, and return a list with the count of occurrences of each word. I'm actually reading the words out of files in a directory, but I can't seem to get the tail-recursion to compile. This is what I have so far:

```
let countOccurence (word:string) list = 
    List.filter (fun x -> x.Equals(word)) list

//(all words being a list of all words across several files)
let distinctWords = allWords |> Seq.distinct

let rec wordCloud distinct (all:string list) acc =
    match distinct with
    | head :: tail -> wordCloud distinct tail Array.append(acc, (countOccurence head all)) //<- What am I doing with my life?
    | [] -> 0
```

I realize this is probably a fairly straightforward question, but I've been banging my head for an hour on this final piece of the puzzle. Any thoughts?

Comment: as Mark already answered there are a few strange going on: in `countOccurrences` do you really want a *word-list* back? It sounds like you want an `int` -  and while I understand that you want to get this running you should be able to do this without *direct recursion* - instead use the higher-order functions in the `List` module instead - `wordCloud` on the other side sounds like you want some kind of `Word * Importance` back but here you give an `int`(?) ... also usually you'll want to give back your `acc` in some form (or it might be useless)

Comment: to make this short: please **add** what you want your functions to do - **best** if you can get a meaningful signature *together* with at least **one example** of what an typical input/output pair should look like - this will be a lot easier to see through than the not-compiling code you got :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the statement as given:

- Use of Array.append to manipulate lists
- Typos
- Incorrect use of whitespace to group things together

Try expressing the logic as a series of steps instead of putting everything into a single, unreadable line of code. Here's what I did to understand the problems with the above expression:

```
let rec wordCloud distinct (all:string list) acc =
    match distinct with
    | head :: tail ->
        let count = countOccurence head all
        let acc' = acc |> List.append count
        wordCloud distinct tail acc'
    | [] -> 0
```

This compiles, but I don't know if it does what you want it to do...

Notice the replacement of `Array.append` with `List.append`.

This is still tail recursive, since the call to `wordCloud` sits in the tail position.

Comment: I just realized I posted a code review request, so I made a separate question on the code review beta. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours more work, I came up with this:

```
let countOccurance (word:string) list = 
    let count = List.filter (fun x -> word.Equals(x)) list
    (word, count.Length)

let distinctWords = allWords |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toList

let print (tup:string*int) =
    match tup with
    | (a,b) -> printfn "%A: %A" a b

let rec wordCloud distinct (all:string list) (acc:(string*int) list) =
    match distinct with
    | [] -> acc
    | head :: tail -> 
        let accumSoFar = acc @ [(countOccurance head all)]
        wordCloud tail all accumSoFar

let acc = []
let cloud = (wordCloud distinctWords allWords acc)

let rec printTup (tupList:(string*int) list) =
    match tupList with
    | [] -> 0
    | head :: tail -> 
        printfn "%A" head
        printTup tail

printTup cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem actually has a pretty straightforward solution, if you take a step back and simply type in what you want to do.

```
/// When you want to make a tag cloud...
let makeTagCloud (words: string list) =
    // ...take a list of all words...
    words 
    // ...then walk along the list...
    |> List.fold (fun cloud word ->
        // ...and check if you've seen that word...
        match cloud |> Map.tryFind word with
        // ...if you have, bump the count...
        | Some count -> cloud |> Map.add word (count+1)
        // ...if not, add it to the map...
        | None       -> cloud |> Map.add word 1) Map.empty
    // ...and change the map back into a list when you are done.
    |> Map.toList
```

Reads like poetry ;)